# Import email addresses from logged-in facebook users?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to develop an application that imports the email addresses of logged-in facebook users who visit my website to facebook-- something like yahoo contact importer and other contact importers.

1. The user 'X' has logged into Facebook.
2. App has a set of friends' UIDs (possible friends of user 'X').
3. I want to get the email addresses of these UIDs, but only UID, birthday, name, first_name, last_name appear in the query result, and the email address appears with NULL. However, I added all extended permissions related to friends, like:

   ```
   (perms:'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages,friends_activities,friends_about_me,user_hometown,user_birthday,user_about_me,user_hometown,user_photos,email,manage_friendlists,read_friendlists')
   ```

Note: I browsed facebook API for developers and could not find any solution.

My code:

```
<body>

<h1>Login to FaceBook using My Web Application</h1>

<div>
  <button id="login">Log In</button>
  <button id="logout">Log Out</button>

  <button id="disconnect">Disconnect</button>

</div>

<div id="user-info" style="display: none;"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
  // initialize the library with the API key
  FB.init({ apiKey: 'c2e2e62acc6a292c20c63404bcfecb23' });

  // fetch the status on load
  FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);

  $('#login').bind('click', function() {
    FB.login(handleSessionResponse,{perms:'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages,friends_activities,friends_about_me,user_hometown,user_birthday,user_about_me,user_hometown,user_photos,email,manage_friendlists,read_friendlists'});
  });

  $('#logout').bind('click', function() {
    FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
  });

  $('#disconnect').bind('click', function() {
    FB.api({ method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' }, function(response) {
      clearDisplay();
    });
  });

  // no user, clear display
  function clearDisplay() {
    $('#user-info').hide('fast');
  }

  // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
  function handleSessionResponse(response) {
    // if we dont have a session, just hide the user info
    if (!response.session) {
      clearDisplay();
      return;
    }

    FB.api(
      {
        method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT pic,hometown_location,name,username, uid, email, sex, birthday FROM user WHERE uid=' + FB.getSession().uid

      },
      function(response) {  
       var user = response[0];

       $('#user-info').html("<img src="+user.pic+"/>"+'<br/>ID: '+user.uid +'<br/>User Name: '+ user.name +'<br/>Email: '+ user.email +'<br/>Birth Day: '+ user.birthday +'<br/>Gender: ' + user.sex+'<br/>Home Town: ' +user.hometown_location['state']).show('fast');

      }
    );

    // if we have a session, query for the user's profile picture and name
    FB.api(
    {
     method: 'friends.get' 
    },
    function(response) 
    {

     $(response).each(function() {
     var userid = this;
     FB.api(
     {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT uid,name,email,birthday FROM user WHERE uid=' + userid
    },function(response) 
    {
    var user = response[0]
     $('#user-info').append('<br/>ID: '+user.uid+ ', Name: '+user.name+' ,Email: '+user.email); 

    });
   });
    }
    );

    }

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get email hashes of user's friends via FQL (field "email_hashes" of table "user").

Another way to bind your users to facebook users - to use method "search" (it can search facebook users by email). I've used it when I had the same problem.

For example, this API call:

```
/search?q=pavel@vbnet.ru&type=user
```

returns:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Pavel Surmenok",
         "id": "100001653100014"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can iterate on your emails and search whether they registered on Facebook.

Comment: sorry i need to extract emails from friendsList of mine after logging in, i don not have any email contacts to check for register

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow to extract emails. You can get only hashes of emails.

Comment: Oh... I thought that if you want to "import emails of logged in facebook user from my website to facebook" then you should have some emails and want to find facebook users with these emails. If I misunderstood you, could you refine your task, please?

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply, I need to do something like yahoo contact importer (facebook) but in my web application.

Comment: It seems that facebook allows access only to the email of logged in user via API, for security reasons.

Comment: See an OpenInviter http://openinviter.com/ . It is an open source software with function of importing facebook contacts. As I see, it doesn't use API, it imitates browser HTTP requests. It seems to be a solution. But I don't know how this approach corresponds with facebook user license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Add email to the perms.You need extended permission to read email address of the user. ie

```
perms:'email,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages,friends_activities,friends_about_me,user_hometown,user_birthday,user_about_me,user_hometown,user_photos,email,manage_friendlists,read_friendlists )
```

Comment: thanx but i already added email permission to perms, check my code